# TSQL - Joining two tables without columns in common

Tags: t-sql, select, join

Basically I have two tables one is a set of values that indicate scoring and the other is the main information for which a score needs to be indicated.

The main information table is (A):

```
Calculations    Results
Profit           0.29
Profit Ratio     0.685
```

The scoring table is fix and has a set of ranges (B)

```
SCORE   GRADE   RATIO START RATIO END
0.0000  Poor    0           0.5
10.0000 Good    0.5         0.5999
20.0000 Great   0.6         0.6999
etc
```

I need a table with the result

```
Calculations    Results Score   Grade
Profit          0.29    0.0000  Poor
Profit Ratio    0.685   20.000  Great
```

I've writen several bits of code so far, but none work. I can't see how I can do a JOIN to then select the Score and Grade when the a.result between b.ratio_start and b.ratio_end without anything to join the two tables on.

I also tried a nested Select statement but got a ton of errors one of which prompted me to use an EXISTS clause, but I don't see how this could be done either.

The last resort would be to scrap using the table (I created the table with figures provided from a department thinking it'd make things easier) and bring the table values into a case statement.

What do you think?

UPDATE
I over "thunk" it!!!
A join without explicitly saying JOIN works xx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A join does not necessarily mean equality:

```
select * 
from inf
join score on (inf.results between score.ratio_start and score.ratio_end);
```

Comment: Oh? I had no idea you could do that!! Thanks will try it too xx